# Não Repetir Valores

Tags: php, javascript

estou utilizando api do google maps e sou meio leigo em js.
O meu mapa exibi marcadores e em cada marcador vou exibir um infowindow ou um balão de informação.
O código abaixo está fazendo isso, porem está repetindo os valores do Array, como faço exibir o valor especifico de cada marcador ou localidade?

```js
for(var i = 0; i<cord.length; i++){
       var contentString = cord[i].local;
        /*var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    //content: contentString
  });*/

        //var location = cord.latlong[i].split(",");
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(cord[i].lat, cord[i].long),
        map: map
    });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { 
           
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
       
    }
```

Comment: O valor repetido está em `contentString` ?

Comment: dá um console.log(i) e me mostra saida, por favor

Comment: contentString na verdade está recebendo cada valor do array. A saida do i é 0 e 1 que são os dois objetos do array No caso:
  var cord = [{
           "lat":"-19.45738", 
           "long":"-44.2416695",
           "local":"Cidade1"
            },
       {
           "lat":"-15.7942287", 
           "long":"-48.0783226",
           "local":"Cidade2"
       }];

Comment: Você está usando o mesmo valor pra todos, com certeza vai sempre ser o último do loop.

Comment: @Bacco como resolvo isso?

Comment: Você precisa associar um valor a cada marker separadamente em vez de jogar numa variável só.

Comment: @Bacco Opa, desculpa: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpQgeR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está sobreescrevendo a variável no *loop*.

Uma solução seria armazenar o nome em cada `marker`:

```
   marker.contentString = cord[i].local;
```

E recuperar o valor com `this`:

```
    infowindow.setContent(this.contentString);
```

Aplicado ao código:

```
for(var i = 0; i<cord.length; i++){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(cord[i].lat, cord[i].long),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infowindow.setContent(this.contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    marker.contentString = cord[i].local;
    console.log(cord[i]);
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/JbJzeB)**.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado @Bacco